# Is there a more elegant implementation of this fit-to-bounding-box coordinate transform in TikZ/PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transformation

I have a plottable function whose normalized domain is [0,1] and whose normalized range is [-1,1]. I also have two TikZ coordinates, `(BOTLEFT)` and `(TOPRIGHT)` defining the bottom left and top right of a bounding box where I would like the plot to appear.

I would like to effect a skewless, rotationless affine linear coordinate transform such that the plot domain/range is fitted exactly to the bounding box. That is, each point (x,y) is mapped to

(x,y) → `(BOTLEFT)` + (`(TOPRIGHT)` - `(BOTLEFT)`) · ((x,y) - (0,-1)) ÷ ((1,1) - (0,-1))

For example, the sine wave

```
\draw[domain = 0:1, samples = 256] plot (\x,{sin(\x*4*pi r)});
```

when subject to the transform, should fit exactly inside the bounding box

```
\draw[red] (-2,5) rectangle (1,8);
```

if `(BOTLEFT)` is (-2,5) and `(TOPRIGHT)` is (1,8).

TikZ supports the `xshift`, `yshift`, `xscale` and `yscale` properties to implement the coordinate transform. However, computing the `xscale` and `yscale` properties manually using coordinate arithmetic would appear to require isolating the *x* and *y* components of `(BOTLEFT)` and `(TOPRIGHT)`. I know this can be done (e.g., by the `let` directive):

```
\coordinate (BOTLEFT) at ({-.2},.5);
\coordinate (TOPRIGHT) at (.1,.8);

\draw let
    \p1 = (BOTLEFT),
    \p2 = (TOPRIGHT) in [domain = 0:1, samples = 256,
        xshift = \x1,
        xscale = (\x2 - \x1)\pts,
        yshift = (\y1 + (\y2 - \y1)/2),
        yscale = ((\y2 - \y1)/2)\pts
        ] plot (\x,{sin(\x*4*pi r)});
\draw[red] (BOTLEFT) rectangle (TOPRIGHT);
```

where `\pts` is a macro that expands to `*<constant>` to convert from pts to the scaling units for the figure, but this seems extremely messy, especially for TikZ/PGF. I can't help but think that TikZ has some kind of built-in to handle this. It would be especially useful if the transform could be `scope`-d, too. That is,

```
\begin{scope}[<set transform here>]
    \draw[domain = 0:1, samples = 256] plot (\x,{sin(\x*4*pi r)});
    <more commands in same coordinate frame>
    ...
\end{scope}
```

Is there a more elegant way of handling this in TikZ, or am I stuck with hacking the coordinate math in this way?

---

### Clarification #1

The coordinates `(BOTLEFT)` and `(TOPRIGHT)` are computed using expressions involving node anchor points, not numeric literals as in the example.

Comment: `\pgfpointanchor{BOTLEFT}{center}` will let `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` be the coordinate of the lower-left corner. That way you can isolate x and y.

Comment: I don't see how this is “extremely messy”. This is a non-trivial transformation and you have to do the math for it in one way or another.

Comment: You can use [shift=(BOTLEFT)] assuming (BOTLEFT) is a coordinate.  Scaling not so easy.

Comment: @HenriMenke: It may indeed be the best/only way to do it. But in my experience, any time I wind up hacking coordinate math in this way, TikZ has a much simpler solution.

Comment: @Symbol1: I'll try that in conjunction with Henri's suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fits (0,0) to (1,1) into (BOTLEFT) to (TOPRIGHT).  It involves the fewest math or conversion steps I could think of.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (BOTLEFT) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (TOPRIGHT) at (2,1);
\fill[black] (BOTLEFT) rectangle (TOPRIGHT);

\coordinate (BOTRIGHT) at (BOTLEFT-|TOPRIGHT);
\coordinate (xscale) at ($(BOTRIGHT)-(BOTLEFT)$);% (3,0)
\coordinate (yscale) at ($(TOPRIGHT)-(BOTRIGHT)$);% (0,2)

\pgfscope
\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpointanchor{xscale}{center}}%
\pgfsetyvec{\pgfpointanchor{yscale}{center}}%
\begin{scope}[shift=(BOTLEFT)]
\node[gray] at (0.5,0.5) {test};
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
\endpgfscope
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works as required. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just apply the transformation in the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    xmin = -.2;
    xmax = .1;
    ymin = .5;
    ymax = .8;
    xaxis(\x) = (xmax - xmin) * \x + xmin;
    yaxis(\y) = (ymax - ymin) * (\y + 1) / 2 + ymin;
  }]

  \draw (xmin,ymin) rectangle (xmax,ymax);
  \draw plot[domain=0:1,samples=256] ({xaxis(\x)},{yaxis(sin(\x*4*pi r))});
  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The actual `(BOTLEFT)` and `(TOPRIGHT)` coordinates are computed using `\coordinate` commands with some fairly involved coordinate math (including anchor points on nodes, etc.), not simple numeric values. Is there a simple variation for this case?